# HBase Cluster setup error

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, hbase

while setting up HBase Cluster setup on AWS  getting the following Error:

```
ubuntu@namenode:~$ hbase/bin/start-hbase.sh

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util. HBaseConfTool
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
starting master, logging to /home/ubuntu/hbase/conf/logs/hbase-ubuntu-master-namenode.out
nice: /home/ubuntu/hbase/conf/bin/hbase: No such file or directory
cat: /home/ubuntu/hbase/conf/conf/regionservers: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you give more details please ? is your Hadoop cluster is running fine ? how did you install HBase ? is HBase managing ZooKeeper ? ...

Comment: I fixed the above error by changing the hbase version.I tried with hbase 0.98 i got this error and I changed it to 0.94 it's working fine.

Comment: It better to find a fix for the problem than to downgrade since 0.98 is now a stable version, you can't use 0.94 forever

Comment: My hadoop version is 1.2.1 and my hbase version is 0.94 working. Here my question is version is okay if i'm using hadoop 1.2.1 with hbase 0.98?

Comment: There are two download versions for HBase 0.98. one for hadoop 1 and the other one for hadoop 2, maybe you were using the wrong version

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughts will check it.

Comment: Hadoop 1.2.1 version is there.I'm sure.